# Why is my project not authorized to use an API key?

Tags: android, http, api-key

I generated API key for my android app that requires map and current location information. API key must be fine because I can access current location and map. But when I tried the following code:-

```
 public void run(){
        String addressURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
                +Double.toString(lat)+","+Double.toString(lon)+"&sensor=true&key="+getString(R.string.api_key);
        Log.d(Globals.TAG, "Request to = " + addressURL);
        httphandler = new HttpHandler(addressURL);
        httphandler.addHttpLisner(MapsActivity.this);
        httphandler.sendRequest();
    }

   if (http.getResCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK
                    || http.getResCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED) {
                String resp = http.getResponse();
 }
```

I get resp = {
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

I don't know why? I am sharing my google console API key settings pictures:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is my API key setting correct? How to use API key for HttpHandler?

Comment: Not an answer, but I have used autocomplete in an Android app, but I didn't make actual HTTP REST calls.  Rather, I used the Android auto complete widget.  Are you sure that it's possible to use the API this way from an Android device?

Comment: Yes, it was all working code. Recently I updated to use the latest location API. After the update, I am facing this issue.

Comment: Question: If you dump that URL into a web browser (placeholders filled in), what response do you get?  Also, do you recall changing anything else, other than upgrading the API level?

Comment: I got the same error message as "This API project is not authorized to use this API. I tried with another API key which is not restricted. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to extend the API restrictions, you have to enable the [Geocoding API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/geocoding-backend.googleapis.com) first ...

then it can be assigned as an "API Restriction" (required because of other restrictions).

for `HTTPS` REST API access, you probably might need no "Application Restrictions",

because this basically equals a web-application accessing the API from dynamic IP ...

nevertheless the `Geocoding API` needs to be enabled for the project and permitted for the key.

if you want IP restriction, you'd have to call with your app to your own web-service, having static IP.

Answer (score 0):

click library on the left search for maps api enable it.

You will probably also have to enable a billing account.